# Updating sqlite3 table with data from tkinter dropdown menu in python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have two tkinter dropdown menus, created using variables `drop_down_var1` and `drop_down_var2`, as well as a tkinter text entry box created using the variable `id_var`.

I want to create an `sqlite3` table with an ID key and with data from these dropdown menus. I want the user to be able to insert data through `drop_down_var1`, and later on I want the user to be able to update the table through `drop_down_var2` and a variable called `id_var`.

I'm struggling with the syntax for **updating** the table. I've seen how it's done when your data is from a
text entry box but not when the data is from a **dropdown** **menu**.

Thanks for any help!

```
# To create table and insert data from dropdown menu 1 
self.db.execute('CREATE TABLE all_users IF NOT EXISTS' + drop_down_var1.get() + drop_down_var2.get() + '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)')
self.db.execute('INSERT INTO all_users' + drop_down_var1.get())

# To update table with data from dropdown menu 2 
self.db.execute('UPDATE all_users SET drop_down_var2 = ? WHERE id = ?', (drop_down_var2, id_var))
```

Comment: what did you try? Did you try to use Google to find documentation or examples? Google alwasy should be your first step.

Comment: BTW: in last `execute()` you forgot `.get()`. Maybe it is all your problem.

Comment: do you get error message ? Always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: BTW: in first and second query you may have to add spaces before values - now you can get `EXISTSoneTWO` instead of `EXISTS one TWO`.  and `all_usersone` instead of `all_users one`. You could assing query to variable and `print()` before `execute()` to see if you created correct query. And then you can also use this query directly in database (with tools like [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.io/)) to see if it works correctly.

Comment: The first two SQL statements are not likely valid SQL syntax.  Better study SQL first.

Comment: @acw1688 That's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It minimal example which shows how to use `StringVar` to get value from `OptionMenu`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- function ---

def on_click():
    print("value1:", drop_down_var1.get())
    print("value2:", drop_down_var2.get())
    #print(self.db.execute('UPDATE all_users SET drop_down_var2 = ? WHERE id = ?', (drop_down_var2.get(), id_var.get())) 

# --- main ---

master = tk.Tk()

drop_down_var1 = tk.StringVar(master)
drop_down_var1.set("one") # initial value

drop_down_var2 = tk.StringVar(master)
drop_down_var2.set("one") # initial value

drop_down1 = tk.OptionMenu(master, drop_down_var1, "one", "two", "three", "four")
drop_down1.pack()

drop_down2 = tk.OptionMenu(master, drop_down_var2, "one", "two", "three", "four")
drop_down2.pack()

button = tk.Button(master, text="OK", command=on_click)
button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

---

Base on documentation on effbot.org: [OptionMenu](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm)

---

**BTW:** If you append to other string then don't forget to add spaces

see spaces after `EXISTS`, between arguments and before `(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)`

```
'CREATE TABLE all_users IF NOT EXISTS ' + drop_down_var1.get() + ' ' drop_down_var2.get() + ' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)'
```

and after `all_users`

```
'INSERT INTO all_users ' + drop_down_var1.get()
```

Using string formating spaces around `{}` are better visible

```
'CREATE TABLE all_users IF NOT EXISTS {} {} (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)'.format(drop_down_var1.get(), drop_down_var2.get())

'INSERT INTO all_users {}'.format(drop_down_var1.get())
```

You can also display string after formatting and test directly in database using tools like [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.io/). Database can give more informatiom if query is incorrect.